# Angular don't set token in Request Header

Tags: node.js, angular, api, http-headers, httprequest

The problem is angular doesn't sent a token to api, Authorization: Token doesn't appear in the Resquest Header( api in Nodejs)

[Network Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3NUG.png)

Heres the component that makes the http request (get with headers)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPets('/api/animals/all');
  }

  getPets(URL) {
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', userToken);
    console.log(headers);
      this.httpClient.get(api_url + URL, { headers } ).subscribe(pets => {
      this.data = pets;
      this.petsHome = this.data.pets;
      console.log(this.petsHome);
    });
  }
```

Heres the api.ts where CORS is defined

```
class Api {

  public express: Application;

  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.middleware();
  }

  middleware(): void {
    this.express.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
      next();
    });
    this.express.use(morgan('dev'));
    this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ));
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.express.use(Handlers.errorHandlerApi);
    this.router(this.express, Auth);
  }

  private router(app: Application, auth: any): void {
    Routes.initRoutes(app, auth);
  }
}
```

export default new Api().express;

The requests don't need token, normally occurs and respond 200 OK. For exemple login where the token isn't needed normally occurs (don't have headers)

[Console.log of Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiEMj.png)

Comment: Can you paste the results of console.log(headers); (Angular)

Comment: I added the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My api is waiting for token in OPTIONS

so... I added this code

```
if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        res.send(200);
        return;
      }
```

This solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization")
```

I'm not sure if the API is called `addHeader`, but you should understand what I mean.

Comment: The addHeader doesn't exist in Nodejs so i set with res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization'); But this doesn't work

Comment: I use `koa2-cors` on nodejs, you can also find a library which works on `Express`

Comment: I try use koa2-cors, but this return 502 for me

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure `.set` will work or not, another way is to using `.append` in headers like this, Please try below code-

```
const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
headers.append('Authorization', userToken);
```

Comment: I already tried the .append, but not work, the result is the same of .set